# enum with function error

Tags: c#, function, methods, enums

i'm a beginner programmer i was write code by using visual basic.net so i'd like to study c#, could one help me to solve this code
hello,what is error with this code?

```
  enum Day
{
    Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday,Thursday, Friday    
}
 public static void ShowDay(Day CurrentDay) // Error
{
    if (CurrentDay == Day.Friday)
        Console.WriteLine("A vacation");
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Day X;
    X = Day.Friday;
    ShowDay(X);
    ShowDay(Day.Friday);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to coding and stackoverflow - you tell us, does it compile? does it not produce what is the error? please read http://www.stackoverflow/help/How-to-asl

Comment: Is the error occuring here `ShowDay(X);` or here `ShowDay(Day.Friday);`?

Comment: public enum Day
{
    Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday,Thursday, Friday    
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make your `enum` public.

```
public enum Day
{
    Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday,Thursday, Friday    
}
```

**UPD**: Or remove `public` from the `ShowDay` method.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, that is not a true statement.  If it is `internal` it is still less accessible than `public` and will not compile.

Comment: We do, because public method exposes its signature to outer world and the outer world must know all about the type of public method's parameter in order to execute it.

Comment: Or just remove public from the method.

Comment: thank you mr.Dmitri Trofimov speed answer,But why was the emergence of this error in spite of the existence enum and function in the same class

Comment: No my answer is redundant since you updated yours. Anyway +1 ;)

Comment: @NourAhmed, because public method exposes its signature to outer world and the outer world must know all about the type of public method's parameter in order to execute it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aLaXJA).

```
public enum Day
{
    Saturday,
    Sunday,
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday
}

public static void ShowDay(Day CurrentDay)
{
    if (CurrentDay == Day.Friday)
        Console.WriteLine("A vacation");
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Day X;
    X = Day.Friday;
    ShowDay(X);
    ShowDay(Day.Friday);
}
```

The issue is that your method was public, yet the the variable type of the parameter was not -- as such it is considered "less accessible".

**Update**

The idea is that the [access modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) must align, there are several key scenarios to consider.

In this case you omitted the access modifier on the `enum` declaration -- this is `internal` for top-level types and `private` for nested types. Now, when you define your method `ShowDay(Day currentDay)` as `public`, that means that it is exposed to anyone who references this class. The issue is that, the parameter is not exposed but you're defining it as a parameter. Does that help?

But it would be fine for the `enum` to be defined as `public` and the method be defined as anything less that `public`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make your method internal by either putting `internal` in front of it or simple removing the `public` keyword.

```
static void ShowDay(Day CurrentDay) // No error
```

Simply put this error occurs because related types and methods need to have the same access modifier. So either make everything public or the method internal.